Jetson NanoにPicamera2をインストールしたい
Jetson Nano開発キットを購入しました。これにCSIカメラを接続して、Raspberry Piと同じようにpicamera2をインストールしたいのですが、以下の通りエラーになります。
pip3もpython3もインストールされています。ご教授お願いします。
$ sudo apt install -y python3-picamera2
E: Unable to locate package python3-picamera2
pipを使ってみましたが、エラーします。
pip install picamera2
pip3 install picamera2
では、
Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement picamera2 (from version: none)
Error: No matching distribution found for picamera2
pip3 install picamera
では、別のエラーが発生します。
教えて頂いたpicamera2.0.3.18-PypIには
Picamera2 is only supported on Raspberry Pi OS bullseye(or later) image.
とあります。
Picamera2はJetson NanoのUbuntuでは使えないのでしょうか？

picamera2 0.3.18 - PyPI に書かれている apt を使ったインストールが上手くいかないのなら、代わりに pip を使ったインストールの方を試してみてはどうでしょう？

こんな記事が何かヒントになるかもしれませんね。[HOW-TO] Install working picamera2 on Ubuntu 22.04? (needs python3-libcamera) #383 あと古い記事ですが Picamera2 ではなく OpenCV を使う例があるようです。Jetson Nano 開発者キットで Raspberry Pi カメラを使う

Ubuntu のパッケージはバージョンが違うだけでも対応状況が異なります。picamera2 はドキュメントを見る限り RasPi 向けのライブラリの様なので、Jetson Nano でそのまま使える保証はありません。

sudo apt install licap-dev,sudo install python3-prctl試しましたが、エラーします。この過去の外国の投稿者もRasberry Pi+Ubuntsuの組み合わせなので、出来たのかもしれません。あきらめて、別の方法で写真を撮るか、Raspberry Piを使用しようと思います。勉強になりました。貴重なアドバイス、ありがとうございました。
